# Getting PowerMock Error: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockmaker.PowerMockMaker

Tags: java, mocking

I am getting PowerMock error but I am not using PowerMocking. I am using normal mocking. This is my class which I want to test:

```java
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class IlinqBeanDataBuilder {

    @Autowired
    private Settings settings;

    private static final String SERVICE_CODE_FOR_FACILITY_COUNTRY = "SERVICE_CODE_FOR_FACILITY_COUNTRY";
    private static final String SERVICE_CODE_A_CONSTANT = "A";

    private static final String HARD_DOWN = "HARD DOWN";
    private static final String QUICK_QUESTION = "QUICK QUESTION";
    private static final String PARTIAL_DOWN = "PARTIAL DOWN";

    private static final String COMPLETELY_DOWN = "Completely Down";
    private static final String UP = "Up";
    private static final String PARTIALLY_DOWN = "Partially Down";

    public RfsData prepareIlinqData(RequestData requestdata) throws FileNotFoundException {

        System.out.println("M into prepare illinq data");
        RfsData iLinkDataBean = new RfsData();
        iLinkDataBean.setCountryCode(requestdata.getCountryCode());
        iLinkDataBean.setSystemId(requestdata.getEquipmentID());
        iLinkDataBean.setModality(requestdata.getModality());
        /**
         * Removing the US from FacilityID In future fix need to change based on
         * some related information
         */
        iLinkDataBean.setCustomerId(requestdata.getFacilityID().substring(3));

        iLinkDataBean.setFirstname(requestdata.getName());
        iLinkDataBean.setPnumber(requestdata.getPhoneNumber());
        iLinkDataBean.setExtension(requestdata.getExtension());
        iLinkDataBean.setDescription(requestdata.getDescription());
        iLinkDataBean.setShortDescription(requestdata.getShortDescription());
        iLinkDataBean.setPeriod(requestdata.getTimePeriod());
        iLinkDataBean.setIlinq_local(requestdata.getLocale());
        iLinkDataBean.setRequestApp(requestdata.getRequestingApp());
        iLinkDataBean.setExamNum(requestdata.getExamNumber());
        iLinkDataBean.setSeriesNum(requestdata.getSeriesNumber());
        iLinkDataBean.setImageNum(requestdata.getImageNumber());
        iLinkDataBean.setRequestorSystemId(requestdata.getEquipmentID());
        iLinkDataBean.setServicecode(requestdata.getServiceCode());
        iLinkDataBean.setIsocode(requestdata.getIsoCode());
        iLinkDataBean.setProblemtype(requestdata.getProblemType());
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(requestdata.getEquipmentStatus())
                || StringUtils.isNotEmpty(requestdata.getEquipmentStatus())) {
            if (requestdata.getEquipmentStatus().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(HARD_DOWN)) {
                iLinkDataBean.setStatus(COMPLETELY_DOWN);
            } else if (requestdata.getEquipmentStatus().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(QUICK_QUESTION)) {
                iLinkDataBean.setStatus(UP);
            } else if (requestdata.getEquipmentStatus().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(PARTIAL_DOWN)) {
                iLinkDataBean.setStatus(PARTIALLY_DOWN);
            } else {
                iLinkDataBean.setStatus(requestdata.getEquipmentStatus());
            }
        }

        String CountryCode = iLinkDataBean.getCountryCode();
        System.out.println("Hi country code is:" + CountryCode);

        String list1 = this.settings.getString("contactge.americas.country.codes");
        System.out.println("list 1 data is:" + list1);

        String list2 = this.settings.getString("contactge.asia.country.codes");
        String list3 = this.settings.getString("contactge.europe.country.codes");
        String list4 = this.settings.getString("contactge.japan.country.codes");
        List<String> RegionList1 = Arrays.asList((list1.split(",")));
        List<String> RegionList2 = Arrays.asList((list2.split(",")));
        List<String> RegionList3 = Arrays.asList((list3.split(",")));
        List<String> RegionList4 = Arrays.asList((list4.split(",")));

        System.out.println("List1 data is:" + RegionList1);
        System.out.println("List2 data is:" + RegionList2);
        System.out.println("List3 data is:" + RegionList3);
        System.out.println("List4 data is:" + RegionList4);
        String RegionCode = null;
        if (RegionList1.contains(CountryCode)) {
            System.out.println("M in list 1");

            RegionCode = "Americas";

        } else if (RegionList2.contains(CountryCode)) {
            System.out.println("M in list 2");
            RegionCode = "ROA";
        } else if (RegionList3.contains(CountryCode)) {
            System.out.println("M in list 3");
            RegionCode = "EMEA";
        } else if (RegionList4.contains(CountryCode)) {
            System.out.println("M in list 4");
            RegionCode = "Japan";
        }

        System.out.println("Region code:" + RegionCode);
        iLinkDataBean.setRegionCode(RegionCode);
        System.out.println("ilinq data bean builder data:" + iLinkDataBean);

        // Getting regionCode from CountryCode using property file
        // iLinkDataBean.setRegionCode(RegionCode);
        System.out.println("system id----------------:" + iLinkDataBean.getSystemId());

        System.out.println("ilinq data bean builder data:" + iLinkDataBean);
        return iLinkDataBean;
    }
}
```

This is my test class. In this, I am mocking setting object which fetch data from database and I am doing inject mock at ILinqBeanDataBuilder.

```java
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;

import junit.framework.Assert;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class IlinqBeanDataBuilderTest {

    @InjectMocks
    IlinqBeanDataBuilder iLinqdata;

    @Mock
    private Settings settings;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Throwable {

        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        // iLinqdata = new IlinqBeanDataBuilder();

    }

    @Test
    public void testCheckSum() throws FileNotFoundException {

        RequestData reqData = new RequestData();
        reqData.setCountryCode("123");
        reqData.setEquipmentID("414541HD01");
        reqData.setModality("sjdksd");
        reqData.setFacilityID("sdjhsdj");
        reqData.setCountryCode("CA");
        reqData.setIsoCode("2");
        reqData.setProblemType("ddddddddd");
        reqData.setProblemArea("ssbnc");
        reqData.setEquipmentStatus("sdsds");
        reqData.setName("pinku");
        reqData.setPhoneNumber("2999999999992");
        reqData.setExamNumber("12323");
        reqData.setServiceCode("sdfsfdf");
        reqData.setExtension("3473437");
        reqData.setDescription("sdsjd");
        reqData.setShortDescription("sjdks");
        reqData.setTimePeriod("01/01/2011,13:00");
        reqData.setLocale("en_US");
        reqData.setRequestingApp("icenter");
        reqData.setImageNumber("sdjsh");
        reqData.setSeriesNumber("2334");
        Mockito.when(settings.getString("contactge.americas.country.codes"))
                .thenReturn("CA,CL,MX,PR,US,AR,BR,GD,VE,CR,PE,AS,DO,HN,PA,CO,BO,GT,JM,EC,PY,UY,NI,SV");
        Mockito.when(settings.getString("contactge.asia.country.codes"))
                .thenReturn("IN,CN,AU,HK,KR,MY,SG,TW,TH,ID,PH,NZ,VN,C3,H2,DV");

        Mockito.when(settings.getString("contactge.europe.country.codes")).thenReturn(
                "AT,BE,CH,DE,ES,FI,FR,GB,IT,NL,PT,SE,UK,NO,DK,PL,RO,ZA,IE,SA,EG,HU,TR,GR,CZ,IL,AE,AL,BG,CS,CY,DZ,IS,JO,KE,KW,LB,LU,MT,MC,MA,RE,RU,SI,SK,TN,UM,AZ,BA,BJ,BY,DI,GE,GF,HR,KZ,LT,LV,MK,UA,YU,OT,NG");
        Mockito.when(settings.getString("contactge.japan.country.codes")).thenReturn("JP");

        RfsData rfs = iLinqdata.prepareIlinqData(reqData);
        System.out.println(rfs.getCountryCode());

        Assert.assertEquals("CA", rfs.getCountryCode());
    }
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
            at org.mockito.internal.creation.MockSettingsImpl.validatedSettings(MockSettingsImpl.java:167)
            at org.mockito.internal.creation.MockSettingsImpl.confirm(MockSettingsImpl.java:161)
            at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:54)
            at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1449)
```

Comment: For your own safety, you might want to go edit out your package name and dependency packages because we can tell who your employer is. I'm not sure their infosec department would appreciate you posting their code like this.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that `Settings` is a final class. Mockito 1.x itself cannot mock final classes and probably tries to mock them by including PowerMock - which you don't have installed.

To solve your issue, you can upgrade to at least Mockito 2.1.0 and enable the [support for mocking final classes and methods](http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.9.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#39). If you need to stick with an older version, either don't mock final classes, or (if you really have no other choice) give PowerMock a try.